# TeamCity error message "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set"

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to initiate a Maven build through TeamCity but we get the following error when trying to build:

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set

When I run my command through CMD the code will compile correctly so this problem seems to only happen when running through TeamCity.

I've tried adding `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME` to the end of the command that TeamCity sends but this only produced the same TeamCity error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to this one. JVM argument needed to be set in TeamCity. So we input:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%env.M2_HOME%
```

Into the JVM command line parameters in TeamCity

Comment: You can also set this as a system property, e.g. Name: system.maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory Value: %env.M2_HOME%